# Non-greedy regex replacement

Tags: python, regex

I have the following file:

```
STRING1
   "string2" = 1 ;
STRING1
   "string4" = 1 ;
STRING1

   "string3" = 1 ;
STRING1
"string5" = 1 ;
```

I wish to replace:

```
STRING1

   "string3" = 1 ;
```

by:

```
STRING1

   "string3" = 2 ;
```

Using `(STRING1.*?".*?".*?=)(.*?)\;` (or even `(STRING1.*?"string.?".*?=)(.*?)\;`) I am able to match the individual `STRING1 ... ;` blocks but if I use `(STRING1.*?"string3.?".*?=)(.*?)\;` the regex match everything up to the string3 block.

Comment: Are you required to use regex? With the small file you described one could easily just read the whole file into a string then use the replace() method and write the new string back to the file. You know what they say: You have a problem. You decide to solve it with regex. Now you have two problems :-)

Comment: This an excerpt of the content of the file, it is significantly bigger. I am not required to use regex but I don't think (but could be mistaken) replace would work because the arrangement of the "string*" can be random. For instance one file could have "string*" \r\n = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `STRING1.*?` when you know `.*?` *cannot* contain particular characters. In this case, it sure looks like `.*?` would be better written as `[^;"]*`. You want a similar substitution for the `".*?=` case.

`(STRING1[^;"]*"string3"[^"=]*=)[^;]*;`

You'll still might need to deal with the case of how quoted strings are are represented in your file. What if one of those strings contains your entire question?

A fully reliable fix would actually parse the whole file looking for the change to make, but that may be overkill for your situation.